# How do I read large numbers precisely in R and perform arithmetic on them?

Tags: r

I am reading a csv file with some really big numbers like 1327707999760, but R automatically converts it into 1.32771e+12. I've tried to assign it a double class but it didn't work because it's already a rounded value. 
I've checked other posts like [Preserving large numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711695/preserving-large-numbers) . People said "It's not in a "1.67E+12 format", it just won't print entirely using the defaults. R is reading it in just fine and the whole number is there." But when I tried to do some arithmetic things on them, it's just not right.
For example:

```
test[1,8]
[1] 1.32681e+12
test[2,8]
[1] 1.32681e+12
test[2,8]-test[1,8]
[1] 0
```

But I know they are different numbers!

Comment: They're not different if you get a difference of 0.

Comment: I'm guessing that `test[2,8] == test[1,8]` will return FALSE.

Comment: @BondedDust actually it returns TRUE. And I think I've found the problem. The thing is that I can't store the large numbers in my csv file! It always shows the scientific format so R can't read it precisely! Any solutions?

Comment: Well then, you really ought to post a bit more detail, don't you agree? (And do look up colClasses in read.table, so that you can read these in as character.)

Comment: @BondedDust Sure. I mean, for example, when I generate the csv file from excel, 1329100082670 would appear like 1.329E+12. I can't make it  show completely and I don't why. Then I found that R can't read 1.329E+12 in the csv precisely as 1329100082670.

Comment: Well _that_ is just plain wrong. I had no trouble reading that value without loss of accuracy. `str(read.csv( text= c('1329100082670', '1329100082670') , header=FALSE)[1,1], digits=16)`  returns `num 1329100082670`

Comment: @BondedDust oh seems the problem is not with R but the csv writer (Excel). I am still seeking some way to write the csv without converting into scientific format...

Comment: So it's not really an R problem at all is it? Excel allows custom formats: Format/Cells/Custom and enter `#0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not large.  It is merely a representation problem.  Try this:

```
options(digits=22)
```

`options('digits')` defaults to 7, which is why you are seeing what you do.  All twelve digits are being read and stored, but not printed by default.

Comment: It seems I've found the real problem...that I can't store the large numbers in my csv file... It always shows the scientific format so R can't read it precisely!

Comment: Well, it's modestly large. It is greater than the old limit on the size of an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Excel allows custom formats: Format/Cells/Custom and enter #0