# How do I read csv with large numbers (probably scientific notation) in R?

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have some 13-digit numbers in an XLS file and I use Excel to generate the CSV file because I need to process it in R.

Then when R read the CSV file, it cannot recognize the big numbers. For example, 1329100082670 would appear like 1.329E+12 in R and lost its precision.

I've tried to format the big numbers as text in Excel and then save it as CSV but that didn't work!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read large numbers precisely in R and perform arithmetic on them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358199/how-do-i-read-large-numbers-precisely-in-r-and-perform-arithmetic-on-them)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The numbers are probably all there, by default R doesn't aways show them. See

```
> a<-1329100082670
> a
[1] 1.3291e+12
> dput(a)
1329100082670
```

The `dput()` shows all the digits are retained even if they display on screen in scientific notation. You can discourage R from using scientific notation by setting the `scipen` option. Something like

```
options(scipen=999)
```

will turn off most scientific notation. But really, what it looks like on screen shouldn't be too important to you hopefully.